# Twig Symfony2 get Request variable

Tags: symfony, twig

I know I can do this:

```
app.request.get('name')
```

...but how do I do this?

```
app.request.get(twig_var_name)
```

I've tried every obvious solution {{}} () etc.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

have you tried :

```
app.request.get('' ~ twig_var_name)
```

Comment: I did but I didn't understand the question neither XD
I tried looking into documentation but I didn't knwo what I should look for. so Can you please explain what your answer means ? 
I know app.request.get('name') is $_GET['name'] but your syntax is different.

Comment: As you said `app.request.get('name') ` is a `$_GET['name']`. But what to do if you want to replace `'name'` by a variable, to get a request value dynamically using a twig variable ? my answer was about that, and what i did was just concating `twig_var_name` which is the twig variable, with an empty string `''`, because `app.request.get()` requires a string parameter. Hope it's clear now for you.

Comment: also `app.request.request.get("whatever")` for post only and `app.request.query.get("whatever")` for get only

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a problem nowadays (Symfony 4.4 and 5 at least).

I've tried getting a request parameter using this:

```
{% set getParamName = 'sort' %}
<input type="hidden" name="sort" value="{{ app.request.get(getParamName) }}" />
```

And there were no issues at all. It works perfectly fine.